# How can I create a context menu for a Delphi component?

Tags: delphi, contextmenu

I want to create a context menu for Delphi components like `TDBGrid`, `TTreeView` or similar. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you mean a context menu for use with a component while designing in the IDE (like right-clicking a TDBGrid and choosing "Columns Editor" from the context menu), or do you mean a context menu for a TDBGrid at runtime within your own application?

Answer (score 8):

Place a TPopupMenu onto your form and design your menu with it. Then select the component the popupmenu is meant for (DbGrid, TreeView, ...) and set it's PopupMenu property to the PopupMenu you just designed.

You can have different PopupMenus for different components.

Answer (score 0):

After placing a TPopupmenu control and linking it to the desired control, if you want to change the available items in the popup menu according to the selected cell or node in a treeview use the OnContextPopup event of the control, that gives you a chance to alter the default behaivor of the Popupmenu